# bigquery with a large number of tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I know there has already been a question regarding the table number limits, but it was vague...
In a dataset I want to create about 1-2 milion tables. This happens because I want to split my users activity table into smaller tables; for each user a table. And in time this number will keep on growing. 
As I understand there will be no problem from BigQuery's perpective...but i'm concerned that I will not  be able to access (list) those datasets from browser (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/appname); because the tables are not grouped by time (like in the case of tables with timerange)  and they get all listed in an endless scroll (possibly blocking the browser)

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: So whats your problem?

Comment: the problem is that the browser will get blocked while listing all tables in the dataset... I can't easily explore my dataset because of this (and query them)

Comment: What possible benefit is there in having so many tables? Especially given that bigquery is good at handling very large data volumes in a single table.

Comment: @matt_black - potential benefit is cost of query. even though BigQuery is columnar and you pay for what columns you query. It still costs you all rows, so if you somehow can decrease number of the queried rows - you save $$ - partitioning/sharding is the way to do so

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant True, but I doubt that having millions of tables is a good solution to cost. Querying millions of rows is still cheap. You would need to experiment with speed and cost given different configurations to be sure of any saving and using rules of thumb from more conventional database setups is likely to be very wrong.

Comment: @matt_black  it actually will save a lot of $ because if I shard the data into small user tables I can use the "list" api option to view a specific users activity...for free...This operation being very frequent in our app. If I wouldn't do this...if I wanted to view a users activity a lot of data had to be processed.

Comment: @matt_black - read my answer again - never said that having million of tables is good idea, rather giving you potential reason of why OP can ended up with this direction. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> … the problem is that the browser will get blocked while listing all
>   tables in the dataset

You can use the "?minimal" parameter to limit the load operation to 30,000 tables per project, so browser will not be blocked. For example:

```
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/<your_project_name>?minimal.
```

see more about [Display limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#limits)

> I can't easily explore my dataset because of this (and query them)

If you are planning to have 2+ million tables in same dataset, even if Web UI were to show them to you without being blocked  - I really doubt you would be able to somehow reasonably visually explore them. Just too many objects to “swallow”
Btw, this is not only human specific issue  - even querying such "long" tables list programmatically can be problematic. See more about [Using meta-tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#tables-meta-table)

> because the tables are not grouped by time (like in the case of tables with timerange) and they get all listed in an endless scroll (possibly blocking the browser)

That’s right, in BigQuery Web UI tables will be grouped only if they follow table_preffixYYYYMMDD pattern. Even if you would map your userID namespace to YYYYMMDD value – you would still be out of luck as your group still will consists of those millions tables.

> Thank you for any suggestions

BigQuery supports [Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) which allows to have multiple partitions in the same table. Unfortunately, as of today, only Date-Partitioned tables are supported, but from what I heard BigQuery Team plans to add partitioning by arbitrary column.
This would probably fit to your desired design, unless there will be a limitation to column cardinality.
Meantime, if you want, you can experiment with applying your design using date-partitioned tables feature by mapping userid to YYYYMMDD (~9999*12*30 >> 3+ million users)

> My recommendation:

1. Play/experiment with partitioned tables as I suggested in previous  (above) section
2. Sharding (splitting) tables in BigQuery to millions of tables sound to me extremely impractical. You should revisit your design. What it is that you are trying to address by such sharding? Try to focus on this and if needed - post specific question here on SO!

Comment: Hi @mikhail, did you have some experience with hashing-splitting- YYYYMMDD? It looks like a nice idea, I also thought about it, but I'm a bit scared :) ( ctrl.alt.d at gmail dot com )

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution for this you can use [Google cloud sdk client](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).

You can read the documentation for this bq Command-Line tool [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool).

eg: `bq ls [project_id:][dataset_id]` to list all tables.

**NOTE**: Maximum tables per query is limited to 1000. [Refer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#limits)